# IE8 and jQuery - not changing background image on toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

This is only an issue in IE8.

```js
$( "#pause" ).bind( "click", function(e) {
    if ( playState == "play" )
    {
        //do other stuff here
        $( "#pause" ).toggleClass( "btn-play btn-pause" );
    }
    else
    {
        //do other stuff here
        $( "#pause" ).toggleClass( "btn-play btn-pause" );
    }
});
```

```css
a.btn-pause, a.btn-pause:visited {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    float: right;
    width: 104px;
    height: 34px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/btn-pause.png);
    width: 104px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
a.btn-play,a.btn-play:visited {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    width: 104px;
    height: 34px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../images/btn-play.png);
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

I have confirmed using Developer Tools that the classes ARE getting toggled as expected (.btn-play and .btn-pause are being appended and removed from the a tag in question). However, the background image is not updating! Again -- this is only an issue in IE8.

I've tried using removeClass() and addClass(), and that made no difference. Tried some other solutions like adding e.stopPropagation(), putting it in a timeout, etc. Nothing has worked.

Comment: So it's not actually a jQuery problem if the classes are changed? More of a CSS problem.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an invalidation issue. At the end of your click handler place `this.className = this.className`. Does this resolve the issue?

Comment: I tried your exact code above (I just left out the playState IF statement) and it worked fine for me in IE8